# Show dropdown option based on user id

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-blade

I need help with my dropdown. Currently the dropdown display all options from database. However, what I want it to display option based on the user id only. For example, this form is for `Urban Seafood`, suppose the dropdown will only display `Urban Seafood` option instead of showing all options. Below is the controller and view blade. Thank you.

Adjustment Controller:

```
public function create() {
    $restorants = Restorant::where(['active' => 1])->get();
    return view('ingredient::adjustments.create', compact('restorants'));
}
```

View:

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="restorant_id">
  <option disabled selected value> -- {{ __('Select an option') }} -- </option>
     @foreach ($restorants as $restorant)
      <option <?php if(isset($_GET['restorant_id'])&&$_GET['restorant_id'].""==$restorant->id.""){echo "selected";} ?> value="{{ $restorant->id }}">{{$restorant->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Isn't it `Restorant::where(['active' => 1])->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();`?

Comment: Tried your solution and got this error -> `Undefined type 'Modules\Ingredient\Models\Auth'.`

Comment: You need `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: Oh yess, it works! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`Auth` facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// ...

public function create() {
    $restorants = Restorant::where('active', 1)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    return view('ingredient::adjustments.create', compact('restorants'));
}
```